# How to change the order of which they are called?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quite inconvenient problem.

Say that I have the following functions

```
function name(namearg){
...
..
}

function handlefailed(){
..
..
}
function handlecover(){
..
..
}
```

Now to my problem, I have alot of hard coded html that can't be changed that is calling both functions like this

```
<a href="javascript:handlecover();javascript:name('MSS')">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:handlefailed();javascript:name('GPS')">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:handlefailed();javascript:name('NPS')">Link</a>
```

The problem is the order of which I'm calling the functions, I first want to see which function that is called, either handlefailed() or handlecover(), and then want to know what name that is sent to the name function.

If I would have called the functions in the other way around I would just have done

```
var theName;

function name(namearg){
  theName = namearg
}

function handlefailed(){
callOtherfunctionInAnotherJavascript(getElements(theName + ".failed"));
}
function handlecover(){
callOtherfunctionInAnotherJavascript(getElements(theName + ".cover"));
}
```

But now this is not possible since I'm calling the name function after the first function.
Is there a way in javascript that "changes" the order of how the functions are evaluated, or do you guys have a clever sollution to my problem, I.E getting the value of the namearg variable and use it in the handlefailed() & handlecover() functions?

Comment: By hard-coded HTML, do you mean that you can't re-write the HTML at all but you can change the JavaScript code?

Comment: @Dino Gambone Yes thats correct, javascript is an include =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var postFix;
function name(namearg){
    callOtherfunctionInAnotherJavascript(getElements(namearg + postFix));    
}
function handlefailed(){ postFix = '.failed'; }      
function handlecover(){ postFix = '.cover'; }
```

Comment: That works almost perfect, I only have one more question, I get an "invalid argument error", do I have to live with this or are there any way to get rid of this error? :P

Comment: Sorry my bad, that was excelent! I just modified it alittle and it worked perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can empty both functions:

```
function handlefailed(){
..
..
}
function handlecover(){
..
..
}
```

and create two new functions that doing what you need

```
function handlefailed2(){
    ..
    ..
    }
    function handlecover2(){
    ..
    ..
    }
```

then call the new functions from inside function name(namearg) according namearg deside to which function you want to call

Comment: Thought of that, but I need to know what fuction (handlecover or handlefailed) that is called, so thats not possible unforunatley, my thought is to create booleans inside handlecover() and handlefailed() and put either of them to true, then inside the name() see if any of those booleans are true, then call another function with name as argument, is that a good sollution or are there any better? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can declare another global, `handleFunc`, and have `handlefailed`/`handlecover` assign which one to call in name.

```
var theName;
var handleFunc = null;

function name(namearg)
{
    if(handleFunc instanceof Function)
    {
        handleFunc(namearg);
        handleFunc = null;
    }

    theName = namearg
}

function handlefailedCallback(namearg){ /* some code */}
function handlefailed()
{
    handleFunc = handlefailedCallback;
}

function handlecoverCallback(namearg){ /* some code */}
function handlecover()
{
    handleFunc = handlecoverCallback;
}
```

This gives you the flexibility to continue using `name` without breaking other areas of the code.

Comment: Gambone Thank you for your answer, a bit of overkill, but I will definetley save this for further use in other projects, I'm not that good at callback functions, so this will most sureley come in handy =)